# Adding values to a data frame conditional on another data frame

Tags: r

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out, even after browsing many similar posts.

I have two data frames, `dvalues` and `svalues`.

`dvalues`:

```
district   districtID   value    state
Badgam     1002          30.2    N/A
Pulwama    1012          10.9    N/A
Kangra     2002          10.2    N/A
Amritsar   3015          29.8    N/A
...
```

and `svalues`:

```
state            stateID
Jammu & Kashmir     1000
Himachal Pradesh    2000
Punjab              3000
....
```

I want to add a value in the state column for each row, conditional on the `districtID` value being between two `stateID` values.

For example, since `Badgam` and `Pulwama` (first two values in File 1) have `districtID` values between 1000 and 2000, the state name should be `"Jammu & Kashmir"`. Similarly, the district `Kangra` with an ID between 2000 and 3000 should have a state name `"Himachal Pradesh"`.

What my final result should look like:

```
district   districtID   value    state
Badgam     1002          30.2    Jammu & Kashmir
Pulwama    1012          10.9    Jammu & Kashmir
Kangra     2002          10.2    Himachal Pradesh
Amritsar   3015          29.8    Punjab
...
```

Out of many attempts, this is the only one that has worked:

```
dvalues$state<-
 ifelse(dvalues$districtID<2000,"Jammu & Kashmir", 
  ifelse(dvalues$districtID>2000 & dvalues$districtID<3000,"Himachal Pradesh",
    ifelse(dvalues$districtID>3000 & dvalues$districtID<4000,"Punjab",
      ifelse(dvalues$districtID>4000 & dvalues$districtID<5000,"Chandigarh",
       ...
```

However, this is slow and ugly, not to mention there are 36 lines - I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thank you, I really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your interval will always remain thousand, then a simple workaround would be -

```
dvalues$stateID <- dvalues$districtID - (dvalues$districtID %% 1000)
dvalues <- merge(dvalues, svalues, by = 'stateID')
```

But in general, for these merge-within-interval sort of situations, I use `data.table`'s `roll` argument -

```
library(data.table)

# converting data.frames to data.tables
svalues <- data.table(svalues)
dvalues <- data.table(dvalues)

# removing state column from dvalues as we will be getting that from svalues
dvalues[,state := NULL]

#setting keys
setkeyv(svalues,'stateID')
setkeyv(dvalues,'districtID')

# merging the data sets based on values in the key columns
# roll = Inf looks for the previous matching value on the key and merges with that
# see help entry for data.table to understand more
svalues[dvalues, roll = +Inf]
```